# How to make a div take remaining vertical space

Tags: html, css

I have a layout as follows -

```
<div style="height:100px;border: 1px solid #F44;">
  <div style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 4px;">Title</div>  
  <div style="background-color: #a0a; padding: 4px;">Content</div>  
</div>
```

The second `div` which contains Content, sticks to the bottom of Title div. Now I want to be able to make the Content div take up the remaining 75px of the height. The problem is that the 
height of the top div is not fixed. Here is a demo of the problem -

http://jsbin.com/pirus/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div style="height:100px;border: 1px solid #F44; overflow: hidden">
    <div style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 4px;">Title</div>
    <div style="background-color: #a0a; padding: 4px; height: 100%;">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is cutting off the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it look like it takes up the whole area by moving the background color to the container and rearranging this a bit.

```
<div style="height:100px;border: 1px solid #F44;background-color: #a0a;">
  <div style="background-color: #ccc; border:4px solid #ccc;">Title</div>  
  <p style='margin:0;padding:3px'>Content</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: No this would not work. I know it seems like it working but its not doing exactly as expected from the question posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Remove height from wrapper div. In that way, height will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a number of different things.

Your best option would be to:

- Set the wrapper to display:table, and set the title and content div's to display:table-row

---

But if you want to get more creative with it you can do any one of these other options instead:

- Remove the 100 pixel height from your outer container so that it is only as tall as it's contents.
- If you want to specify the height of the outer container, you can specify the height of your inner elements as well (example: Title 25px, Content 75px; or Title: 25%, Content 75%.
- If your outer container is supposed to represent the full height of the page you can set your content height to 100vh which is 100% of the viewport height.
- If you want to be very explicit about it you can set the height of the Content div with javascript:

  ```
  var contentH = ($('.wrapper').height() - $('.title').height());        
  $('.content').css('height',contentH);
  ```